# Combined In_array inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach

i am having trouble using multiple in_array inside `foreach()` loop,
i want to find the key where say metal and prod id's match a given set of m(for metal), p(for prod).

The code is:

```
 $arr = array(

       0 =>array(
         'metal'=>0,
         'prod'=>0
       ),

       1 =>array(
         'metal'=>1,
         'prod'=>1
       ),

      2 =>array(
        'metal'=>2,
        'prod'=>2
      ),

     3 =>array(
      'metal'=>3,
      'prod'=>3
     )
);

$m=1;$p=1;


foreach($arr as $k => $v)
{
//print_r($v);
 foreach($v as $r) {
    if(in_array($m,$v) && in_array($p,$v)) {
        echo $k;
        echo '<br>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'no';
        echo '<br>';
    }

}

}
```

The output:

```
   no
   no
   1
   1
   no
   no
   no
   no
```

So for 0th, 2nd,3rd array it gives no, and where it found the value it gives, key, i want to get the key, for both of the in_array combined (key should be echo'ed only when both in_array are true). and also once it finds it should break,, so that it will not go to else.
i tried using break, but it did not work as expected.

Comment: The OP's logic is flawed, you should not be using `in_array` like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuikes! you go a lot going on there.  First of don't be afraid to use more verbose variables, it will help with reading the code.

That said I think you are one level to deep

```
$metal=1;$prod=1;


foreach($arr as $k => $v){
//print_r($v);  = ['metal'=>0, 'prod'=>0]
   if( $v['metal'] == $metal && $v['prod'] == $prod )
        echo $k;  //should be an int like  0,1,2
        echo '<br>'; 
        break;
    }else {
        echo 'no';
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
```

The other issue you have, is you have to identify the items, you cant just do `in_array` and hope for the best.

Consider this

```
  $array = ['metal' => 2, 'prod'=>1]

  //matches with in_array in the wrong order
  $prod = 2;  //$array['prod'] = 1
  $metal = 1; //$array['metal'] = 2

  //matches with in_array 2x on $array['prod'] 
  $prod = 1;  //$array['prod'] = 1
  $metal = 1; //$array['metal'] = 2
```

If you use in_array, like you had this will pass, because both `1` and `2` are in the array, however they are not where they need to be. Is that the behaviour that you want? This is what I call a nieve implementation, because it does not consider any edge cases.

In fact, calling `in_array( 1, $array)` two times will match the above case as well. It is redundant, because `1` will match `$array['prod'] = 1` two times.

**FURTHER**

Your `break` did not seem to work because you have 2 loops, that are nested.  It actually does work, but when you call break in the inner one it exits that loop, but is still within the parent loop.  Essentially ( with your code ) this has no effect because the inner loop was done evaluating the `if` and exits anyway.

The way to fix that ( in the case you have 2 loops, or a switch in a loop ) is to use the level of the break.  For example:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
//print_r($v);
 foreach($v as $r) {
    if(in_array($m,$v) && in_array($p,$v)) {
        echo $k;
        echo '<br>';
        break 2;  //notice the 2, break out of parent loop
    }else{
        echo 'no';
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Cheers!